# Border-radius: 50% produces jagged circles; why not perfect circles?

Tags: css

I found other threads with similar titles, but I couldn't find a solution that works for me in those threads.

I'm trying to produce input labels that are perfect circles by combining equal width/height with border-radius:50%, but the edges come out pixelated. I've tried various pixel values (both even and odd) for width/height, but the problem remains.

How do I make the circles perfect?

Comment: Define "perfect". ;) On any pixel-based screen it will never be a perfect circle. In your example the circles look fine to me, but the additional border  makes it a bit blurry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Paul. Adding border: 0, as stanze told me to try, did indeed do the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this `border: 0;` CSS property in this `#mobile-choice-buttons label`, and check:)

Answer (score 2):

What you want, as far as I understand, is to anti-alias the shape.
Instead of giving transparent you can make use of `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` for the border. This again gives transparent. But the `alpha=0` makes smooth edges.

```
#circle { 
       width: 140px;
       height: 140px;
       background: blue; 
       -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
       -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
       border-radius: 70px;
       border: 0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
    }
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdLo0fz4/).

And [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba) is the browser support for alpha values.

Comment: this is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;` in the below class.

```
ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
  /* border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; */
```

I see perfect circle without pixel distraction.

Comment: That's because I implemented stanze's solution!

Answer (score 1):

Upon inspecting your css, it seems jQuery UI already has a `grey border` for the `circle`.

```
.ui-state-default, 
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { /* CSS */ }
```

Which is responsible for the jagged circle.  Reset the `borders` to `0` for all the circle elements.

Still the edges(borders) will be somewhat jaggered.  Give a try adding browser's prefixed properties like

```
-webkit-border-radius
-moz-border-radius
```

If you're trying to have a perfect circle, svg or images will be better option